# Use FBSDKShareMediaContent in FBSDKShareAPI

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

Is it possible to use FBSDKShareMediaContent to add image and video with FBSDKShareAPI? I would like to share video + image + message in one post. Adding FBSDKSharePhotoContent or FBSDKShareVideoContent as shareContent into FBSDKShareAPI works fine. Or is there any other way to share both media items with a message in one post without using default share dialog? In default share dialog you can't add message

for example:

```
FBSDKShareAPI * shareApi = [[FBSDKShareAPI alloc]init];
shareApi.message = @"test message";

NSString *videoPath = local_video_path;
FBSDKShareVideo *video = [FBSDKShareVideo videoWithVideoURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath]];

FBSDKShareVideoContent *videoContent = [[FBSDKShareVideoContent alloc] init];
videoContent.video = video;

FBSDKSharePhoto *photo = [FBSDKSharePhoto photoWithImage:local_photo_as_uiimage userGenerated:YES];

FBSDKSharePhotoContent *photoContent = [[FBSDKSharePhotoContent alloc] init];
photoContent.photos = @[photo];

FBSDKShareMediaContent *content = [[FBSDKShareMediaContent alloc] init];
content.media = @[photoContent, videoContent];

shareApi.shareContent = content;
[shareApi share];
```

Comment: Did you find a way, was much better for they deprecated most of the FBSDKShareLinkContent attributes...